# Is it possible to "star" an item using the Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api

It looks like one can query for and read starred items.

Does the api expose an option to allow a user to star an item in app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, look for labels.starred at:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files

You can see what it would look like to send a PATCH request which would star a given fileId using the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v2/drive.files.patch?fileId=1234&_h=2&resource=%257B%250A%20%20%2522labels%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%2522starred%2522%253A%20true%250A%20%20%257D%250A%257D&).

Comment: After having manually starred a document in Drive UI, when performing a GET request using the API, star status update is often VERY delayed. Don't know why.